# Locating specific string fragment inside NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Suppose I have the following string:

`Mary had a little lamb, she also had a little sheep.`

My goal is to extract every word after `had` and before the period. (In this case `a little sheep`).

I tried this way:

```
- (NSInteger)indexOf:(NSString*)substring from:(NSInteger)starts {
    NSRange r;
    r.location = starts;
    r.length = [self length] - r.location;

    NSRange index = [self rangeOfString:substring options:NSLiteralSearch range:r];
    if (index.location == NSNotFound) {
        return -1;
    }
    return index.location + index.length;
}
```

As in:

`NSInteger sheepSpot = [string indexOf:@"had" from:23];`

```
// I know that I want to grab everything after the index of sheepSpot but before the period.
// Suppose now that I have an arbitrary number of periods in the sentence, how can I extract the above text without getting the wrong thing?
```

Comment: what would be the result for a string like this `@"had Mary had a little lamb, she also had a had littlhade sheep.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
-(NSRange)lastRangeOf:(NSString *)substring inString:(NSString *)string{
   return  [string rangeOfString:substring options:NSBackwardsSearch];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSString *string=@"had Mary had a little lamb, she also had a had little sheep.";
    NSString *word=@"had";
    NSRange hadRange=[self lastRangeOf:word inString:string];
    NSInteger start=hadRange.location+word.length;
    NSInteger lengthToCut=string.length-start;
    NSString *substring=[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start,lengthToCut)];
    NSLog(@"->%@",substring);
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping in your `lastRangeOf:inString:` method? Why not use the `rangeOfString:options:` method and pass `NSBackwardsSearch` for the options. No need for a loop.

Comment: @rmaddy: Oh yeah, didn't knew about that api.

Comment: He did say "before the period" and "Suppose now that I have an arbitrary number of periods in the sentence" which I think means that he can have other sentences along with this one and needs to stop looking upon finding the first period.

Answer (score 1):

This code will find the last "had" and the last period and give you everything in between:

```
NSString *text = @"Mary had a little lamb, she also had a little sheep.";
NSString *subtext = nil;
NSRange lastHadRange = [text rangeOfString:@"had" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (lastHadRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange lastPeriodRange = [text rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if (lastPeriodRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSUInteger start = lastHadRange.location + lastHadRange.length;
        NSUInteger length = lastPeriodRange.location - start;
        subtext = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, length)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Subtext is: %@", subtext);
```